# Why was this question locked?

Tags: discussion

Why was this question locked?

[Why are cortisone injections deleterious for tendons?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/170/43) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170506174223/https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/170/why-are-cortisone-injections-deleterious-for-tendons/217))

The post was locked because I indicated I had crossposted the question on Quora. However, doing so is accepted by the Stack Exchange community ([Am I allowed to indicate crosspost links in my questions on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293150/178179))

It is annoying that the question is locked as users cannot answer the question or improve existing answers.

Comment: I can answer it...

Comment: JohnP has just unlocked the answer (guessing from your edit, you'll probably have found out). You can see all information in the edit-history, just in case you were not yet aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JohnP has just unlocked the answer, problem solved.